# Delete data with subselect and multiple primary key fields and conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have this data:

```
MyDate      id     hour   Value   insertionTime           id_agent
----------  -----  -----  ------  ----------------------  --------
2013-12-18  14     17     63      2013-12-18 11:35:47     10
2013-12-18  14     18     63      2013-12-18 11:35:47     10
2013-12-18  14     18     13      2014-01-14 11:02:27     10
2013-12-18  14     19     63      2013-12-18 11:35:47     10
2013-12-18  127    20     63      2013-12-18 11:35:47     10
...
```

I need to delete all the columns that have an `insertionTime` different than `2014-01-14 11:02:27` and have another row for the same `MyDate`, `id` and `hour`.

I don't know how to do it on a single `DELETE` execution. I cannot use an aggregate function and since there is multiple keys on the PK I don't know how to make a subselect.

Ideally, it would be something like:

```
DELETE FROM Table1 WHERE MyDate = @ADate AND id_agent = 10
AND insertionTime <> '2014-01-14 11:02:27' AND AllMyTableKeys IN
 (SELECT AllTableKeys FROM Table1 WHERE MyDate = @ADate  AND id_agent = 10
  GROUP BY AllTableKeys HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

In the example I want to delete the second row.

Comment: Could you explain what would you like to delete in you example?

Comment: @PeterRing Reached the solution with `EXISTS`. I wanted to delete, in the example, the second row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made to the solution using [`EXISTS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx#fbid=WNFeLGWppZU):

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable a WHERE MyDate = '12/18/2013' AND id_agent = 10
AND insertionTime <> '01/14/2014 11:02:27' AND EXISTS 
  (SELECT * FROM MyTale b WHERE a.MyDate = b.MyDate AND a.hour = b.hour
   AND a.id = b.id AND insertionTime = '01/14/2014 11:02:27' AND id_agent = 10)
```

To put that into a `DELETE` form is:

```
DELETE a FROM MyTable a WHERE...
```